# .loc on multiple columns with the same condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to select rows using .loc with a single condition that multiple columns have to meet:

```
# %%
a = (100, 50, 75, 100, 100, 50)
b = (100, 25, 15, 100, 75, 50)
c = (100, 75, 50, 100, 100, 25)

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(a, b, c), columns = ['A' , 'B' , 'C'])

col_lst = ('A' , 'B' , 'C')
```

Those two lines "should" produce the same output:

```
df.loc[df[col_lst] == 100]
    Out: 
ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key

df.loc[(df['A'] == 100) & (df['B'] == 100) & (df['C'] == 100)]
    Out:
    A   B   C
0   100 100 100
3   100 100 100
```

Is it not possible to use .loc with a list of labels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the tuple into list and combine with `all` in axis=1:

```
df[(df[list(col_lst)] == 100).all(1)]
#df.loc[(df[list(col_lst)] == 100).all(1)]
```

Comment: Great, thank you! Can you explain why the .all(1) is needed? I had it converted to a list before your answer but it still does not work without the .all(1).

Comment: @fynn `all(1)` is nothing but [`df.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) across axis 1 , so if all of the columns in `col_list` meets the condition , it returns a boolean series of true else false try `print((df[list(col_lst)] == 100).all(1))`, we can then use a [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)